# paramiko ls with several files output truncated

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, paramiko, ls

I've used paramiko's exec_command with ls succesfully until I tried it with a list of files as an argument. My function is:

```
def jz_orion_ssh_sout_list(cmd):
    with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(orion['host'], username=orion['username'], password=orion['password'])
        ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        sout = ssh_stdout.readlines()
        serr = ssh_stderr.readlines()
        return sout
```

When `cmd='ls -l /my/path/file.txt'` it works fine, but when `cmd='ls -l /my/path/file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt'`, it only returns file1.txt. The latter cmd run directly on the target server returns all 3 files.

How to make it work in paramiko?

PS. I've found another syntax which works in paramiko: `cmd='ls -l /my/path/{file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt}'` but still I'd like to know what causes the failure with beforementioned one.

Comment: why not use `ls -l /my/path/file[1-3].txt` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your `cmd` issue:
For instance, I have 3 files under example folder:

```
➜ ls example
file1 file2 file4
```

file2 is not found:

```
➜ ls -l example/file1 file2
ls: file2: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r--  1 haifzhan  staff  391 28 Nov 10:23 example/file1
```

`ls -l example/file1 file2` is telling `ls` file2 is under current directory other than under folder example.

If we run the command just for file1 and file2

```
➜ ls -l example/file[1-2]
-rw-r--r--  1 haifzhan  staff  391 28 Nov 10:23 example/file1
-rw-r--r--  1 haifzhan  staff   81 28 Nov 10:26 example/file2
```

Alternatively:

```
ls -l example/file1 example/file2
-rw-r--r--  1 haifzhan  staff  391 28 Nov 10:23 example/file1
-rw-r--r--  1 haifzhan  staff   81 28 Nov 10:26 example/file2
```

In your case `ls -l /my/path/{file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt}` works is that you are telling `ls` that all your files are under `/my/path`